# Hibernate ("showSql", "true") in javaconfig doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA with Hibernate as persistence provider, and I configure it with below configuration class.
The problem is that I never see SQL statements compiled by Hibernate though I have showSql=true in additional properties. Please check below. Now it is `properties.setProperty("hibernate.showsql", "true");`, but I also tried `properties.setProperty("showSql", "true");` with no effect.
I don't have persistence.xml and I don't use root-context.xml.
My servlet-context.xml contains only

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <task:annotation-driven />
```

Also, my meta-inf/log4j.xml has all loggers on INFO level including

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL">
    <level value="info" />
</logger>
```

which I added without any effect as well.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com")
public class MySQLconfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
          LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
          em.setDataSource(dataSource());
          em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com" });

     em.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
          JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
          em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
          em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
          return em;
       }


    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"); 
        hikariConfig.setUsername("user");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("user");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(30000);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(30000);
        hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        return dataSource;
    }


     @Bean
       public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
          JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
          transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
          return transactionManager;
       }

     @Bean
       public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
          return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
       }

       Properties additionalProperties() {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class");
          properties.setProperty("hibernate.showSql", "true");
          return properties;
       }

}
```

Comment: `hibernate.show_sql`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property key should be `hibernate.show_sql`, not `hibernate.showSql`.

---

To verify, you can take a look at Hibernate class [`AvailableSettings`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/AvailableSettings.java#L445), which lists the available configuration options, one of which is:

```
/**
 * Enable logging of generated SQL to the console
 */
String SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I googled how this property should be used in javaconfig, but fail to find it, so decided it should be the same as in xml